# The opposite of "technical skills"

Tags: phrase-requests, vocabulary

If *technical skills* include things like familiarity with certain software packages, programming languages, CAD, etc., what is a general term for the other kind of skills, such as fluency in foreign languages, media relations, internet marketing, etc.?  I wanted to suggest "soft skills" for a friend's resume, but that doesn't seem to fit, according to the dictionary ("personal attributes that enable someone to interact effectively and harmoniously with other people").  What term can I use for the section of the resume where skills such as foreign languages, media relations, internet marketing, etc., are listed?

Comment: The ones you list are all communication skills.... and rather specialized skills at that.  I might suggest "Specialized Communication Skills" or "Advanced communication skills".  At some point (very quickly so) this becomes more an exercise in best "resume' writing" practices more than English ... and choices like how many subheadings are ideal etc.

Comment: I definitely agree with the statement about it being really more about resume skills. There are so many good options. The ones Tom suggested are just as good as the ones I suggested.

Comment: Have you tried [workplace.se]?

Comment: You can list foreign languages in an **Other** section.  Sometimes it makes sense to make a section called **Education and Other** and list languages there, after education.  Normally it's better to emphasize skills like *media relations*, *Internet marketing*, etc. in **Work Experience** - the bullets under the various jobs should include this kind of work.  Employers will accept *technical skills* in a separate section but they want to see the non-technical, non-language skills you mention coming through in the work experience.  They won't just accept a person claiming to have them.

Comment: Related abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Soft skills. [More details on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_skills):

> "Soft skills are a combination of people skills, social skills, communication skills, character traits, attitudes, career attributes, social intelligence and emotional intelligence quotients among others that enable people to navigate their environment, work well with others, perform well, and achieve their goals with complementing hard skills."

Comment: Any reason why you voted -1? Just voting -1 without a reason is itself worthy of -1.

Answer (score 0):

Language/Media Skills, Other Skills, Auxiliary Skills, Additional Skills, Supplementary Skills.

And, yes, you are correct, do not use "soft skills". That relates more to a persons ability to interact and socialize.

**EDIT:** Adding a link

["Additional Skills specifically listed under the Formatting Section of the page](https://resumegenius.com/how-to-write-a-resume/skills-section-writing-guide)

> Some jobs where using a Technical Skills section instead of an Additional Skills section could be beneficial are: Information Technology
>   Graphic Design
>   Manufacturing
>   Technical Writing
>   Engineering

**EDIT** I have 25 years of resume writing experience and I'm a software manager who has worked in the technical field for that amount of time as well. I have written hundreds of resumes for friends, myself, and other colleagues over the years. There are literally tons of other good examples too. Tom22 mentioned some great ones in his comments. These options are good, but it's definitely best if you can keep sections focused on specific skill categories (i.e. Language/Media Skills or Specialized Communication Skills).

Answer (score 0):

***Non-technical skills*** would simply be the exact opposite, and it has countless usage examples on [Google](https://google.com/#q=non+technical+skills); and a lot of the search results lead to resume writing "tips and tricks" websites.

For further help on resume writing, do check out the [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and see what's on topic there. Please see if your question has already been asked before asking new.